# I want to use NetInfo React Native, my NetInfo function can be used in all components?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-community-netinfo

```
 componentDidMount() {

    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
        'connectionChange',
        this._handleConnectivityChange

    );

    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {

      if(isConnected == true)
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Online"})
      }
      else
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Offline"})
      }

    });
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {

    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
        'connectionChange',
        this._handleConnectivityChange

    );

  }

  _handleConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {

    if(isConnected == true)
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Online"})
      }
      else
      {
        this.setState({connection_Status : "Offline"})
      }
  };
```

In the application that I made, it has many components, but I want to check whether the user has internet access and call the Netinfo function in all components, without writing it down again

Comment: Please checkout topics like Context, renderProps, HOC, event emitters or hooks. I don't know if subscribing to netInfo in all the components is right way of doing.

Comment: Ok, Can U send me link ?.